# Counting odd entries of Catalan numbers in a square array

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

The number of odd binomial coefficients $\binom{n}k$ in the $n^{th}$-row of the Pascal triangle equals to $2^{s(n)}$, where $s(n)$ denotes the number of $1$’s in the $2$-ary (binary) expansion of $n$.

Let $C_k=\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k$ be the familiar [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). I'm interested in the enumeration of odd terms inside a square arrangement. In detail,

> **QUESTION.** what is the number $O_n$ of odd Catalan numbers $C_{i+j}$ if $0\leq i, j\leq n-1$? It amounts to asking how many entries of the $n\times n$ matrix $M_n=\left(C_{i+j}\right)_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ are odd? I believe it equals $2n-1$. Can you provide a proof?

**JUST FOR FUN.** It's known that $\det(M_n)=1$ and $C_n$ is odd iff $n=2^k-1$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The entry $C_m$ appears $m+1$ times in $M_n$ if $m\le n-1$. If $n\le m\le 2n-2$ then $C_m$ appears $2n-1-m$ times. Suppose $k$ is the largest integer satisfying $2^k-1\le n-1$. Then we have $n\le 2^{k+1}-1\le 2n-1$ and $2n+1\le 2^{k+2}-1$. Therefore the number of odd entries is
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i\right) + (2n-2^{k+1})=2n-1$$
as desired.